# java.lang.ClassCastException: I cannot cast a superobject to a subobject

Tags: android, inheritance, casting, encapsulation, classcastexception

I am a newbie at Android.

To reuse and encapsulate, I write a `BaseIntent` class that extends the `Intent` class to record which class calls my activity, and rewrite `startActivity` and `getIntent` to use my `BaseIntent`. But when I start an `Activity` with a `BaseIntent` instance and want to use `getIntent` to get a `BaseIntent` object, but I get a `ClassCastException`. 
My repo in Github: https://github.com/LeoFate/MusicPlayer
Here is my code:

```
 public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int layout;
    protected String callClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        callClass = getIntent().getCallClass();
        setContentView(layout);
        initView();
    }

    public abstract void initView();

    public void setLayout(int layout) {
        this.layout = layout;
    }

    public BaseIntent getIntent() {
        return (BaseIntent) super.getIntent();
    }

    public void startActivity(BaseIntent intent) {
        super.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

```
public class BaseIntent extends Intent {
    private final String KEY = "ClassName";

    public BaseIntent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) {
        super(packageContext, cls);
        putExtra(KEY, packageContext.getClass().getName());
    }

    String getCallClass() {
        return getStringExtra(KEY);
    }
}
```

```
public class LaunchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        BaseIntent intent = new BaseIntent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements LoginContact.View {
...
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setLayout(R.layout.activity_login);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

```
2019-05-03 10:45:34.850 20582-20582/com.example.admin.cloudmusic E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.admin.cloudmusic, PID: 20582
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.cloudmusic/com.example.admin.cloudmusic.Login.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.Intent cannot be cast to com.example.admin.cloudmusic.Base.BaseIntent
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3303)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.Intent cannot be cast to com.example.admin.cloudmusic.Base.BaseIntent
        at com.example.admin.cloudmusic.Base.BaseActivity.getIntent(BaseActivity.java:25)
        at com.example.admin.cloudmusic.Base.BaseActivity.getIntent(BaseActivity.java:6)
        at android.app.HwActivitySplitterImpl.getDefault(HwActivitySplitterImpl.java:264)
        at huawei.android.common.HwFrameworkFactoryImpl.getHwActivitySplitterImpl(HwFrameworkFactoryImpl.java:618)
        at huawei.android.common.HwFrameworkFactoryImpl.getHwActivitySplitterImpl(HwFrameworkFactoryImpl.java:614)
        at android.common.HwFrameworkFactory.getHwActivitySplitterImpl(HwFrameworkFactory.java:945)
        at android.app.HwCustActivityImpl.isRequestSplit(HwCustActivityImpl.java:42)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:1062)
        at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:75)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:335)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85)
        at com.example.admin.cloudmusic.Base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:12)
        at com.example.admin.cloudmusic.Login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:34)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7383)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921) 
2019-05-03 10:45:34.869 20582-20582/com.example.admin.cloudmusic I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20582 SIG: 9
```

My solution:

```
public class BaseIntent {
    private static final String KEY = "ClassName";

    public static Intent get(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, cls);
        intent.putExtra(KEY, packageContext.getClass().getName());
        return intent;
    }

    static String getCallClass(Intent intent) {
        return intent.getStringExtra(KEY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have to take a look in more detail, but the error is presumably caused by the fact that `super.getIntent()` returned an `Intent` that is not an instance of `BaseIntent`. I'm not sure why. A stack trace (the full error) would help confirm this and identify the root cause.

---

Looking at the stack trace, although there is some code missing, I think the problem is that when you called `LaunchActivity#onCreate` from `LoginActivity#onCreate`, you never specified an `Intent`, causing it to use a built-in one, which is not an instance of `BaseIntent`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I just put the stack trace on it.

Comment: I am new on this site and if my clarification is not clear, please point out.

Comment: @LeoFate If you call `LaunchActivity#onCreate` from `LoginActivity#onCreate` without specifying a (`Base`)`Intent` *first*, that would cause the problem.

Comment: @LeoFate I have to go now. Hopefully this helps you enough, and if not I can take another look in the morning, preferably with the full code, especially of `LoginActivity#onCreate`.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you say, when I start `LoginActivity` from `LaunchActivity`, doesn't I use a n instance of `BaseIntent`?

Comment: Thank you again! I will try to fix it with your answer.

Comment: @Actually, I think I misread the stack trace; it is actually a problem with how `LoginActivity` is started.

Comment: I find the problem, I must let `LaunchActivity#startActivity()` be the `BaseActivity#startActivity`.

Comment: @LeoFate My comment from earlier that I couldn't post due to internet glitchiness: Actually, I think I misread the stack trace. The problem is that `LoginActivity#onCreate` is not being started with a `BaseIntent` for some reason. Perhaps it gets started differently than expected, or doesn't get passed the `Intent` directly, using a wrapper instead? The problem is almost certainly that the `Intent` is not a `BaseIntent`, for some reason.

Comment: Yes, by debug, I find that I use a `BaseIntent` to start `LoginActivity` but when I use getIntent to get the Intent, it cannot be cast to an instance of `BaseIntent`. And I actually don't know much of how it is implied in the source code(`Activity` class), so I give up encapsulate a subclass of `Intent` and use another way to reach my goal. (I put it above.) No matter what, I still want to say thanks to you.

Comment: @LeoFate I'm glad I could help, and hope you can figure it out! Looking at it again, my best guess is that in the process of going through Android's internals, a new object that only copies fields that are on the base class (`Intent`) to a new instance of it, via marshalling/serialization and then the reverse.

Comment: It makes sense, the precise truth is hard for me now, at least I know that I am better to use `Intent` now!